# Unable to add Place Autocomplete in android app

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, location

> My Scenario
>
> I am building an android application where I have used Google map.
>
> I am using API that provides me google location name in Json form and
>   I add that name on my adapter that displays the hint of the location.
>   I have implemented Place AutoComplete in the app to give me
>   auto-suggestions such as India, Indore etc. when I type "I".
>
> Problem Statement
>
> My array list of Json reture NULL, but it should return list of values
>   with auto-suggestions.
>
> Here is my code

```
whitebord.setThreshold(0);
names=new ArrayList<String>();
whitebord.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{

 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{

}

 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int count, int after)
 {

  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
  int before, int count)
  {


  search_text= whitebord.getText().toString().split(",");
  url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?  
  input="+search_text[0]+"&sensor=true&key="+browserKey;
  if(search_text.length<=1){
 names=new ArrayList<String>();
 Log.d("URL",url);
  paserdata parse=new paserdata();
  parse.execute();

 }
  }
 });

public class paserdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


 JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
 json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url.toString());
if(json !=null)
 {
try {
// Getting Array of Contacts
contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);

 for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
 JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
String description = c.getString("description");
Log.d("description", description);
 names.add(description);


}
} catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();

 }
 }

return null;
 }  


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names) {
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
 TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
return view;
 }
 };

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result+"",
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 whitebord.setAdapter(adp);


 }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android ?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you have built a request url, but you have not use any `HttpURLConnection` to make a API request. Also, you need to make sure the internet connection permission is added in your android manifest file.

Comment: How to make httpUrlconnection request

Answer (score 0):

Your code it's correct, but if you don't register your account as billing account, you'll can't use the api. Take a look at :https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?pli=1